# How to resolve android gradle issue in cordova build

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I am facing the following uissues frequently and unable to build an apk because of this:

```css
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not download artifact 'support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1)'
   > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/24.1.1/support-v4-24.1.1.aar'.
      > peer not authenticated
```

Also, I get the error:

```css
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"...\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\...\...\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

Comment: are you using this plugin ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-support-v4

Comment: no, i am not using it as a plugin.

Comment: please try with above mentioned plugin. That uses jar fie so there may not arise gradle error.

Comment: @Smitha Looks more of a certificate issue in HTTPS connection. Try downloading the valid certificate from  https://jcenter.binary.com and import it to JDK's cacerts keystore.  You can refer the link - http://www.thesqlreport.com/?p=576 for certificate import

Comment: Plugin did not help me. And also, running cordova build gave me error code 1 as described.

Comment: I could resolve - .aar certificate issue, but, not - Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"...\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\...\...\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"

Comment: @Smitha That seems to be generic error. Could you help us narrow down the issue with some more info?

Comment: Thats all the error I get when i run cordova build android.. could you suggest if we can add any stacktrace?

Comment: @Smitha Is it possible to share project on github so that we can build locally and see? Also add comments with @ USER_NAME so that the user gets notified too