# Android Studio Gradle Version Issue

Tags: gradle, android-studio-2.1

I have following issue, cannot compile my app

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':xxxxx'.
>
> Could not find support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1).
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/24.1.1/support-v4-24.1.1.aar

My Module App build.gradle file like this:

> compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
>
> compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
>
> compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'

Any help, Thanks!

Comment: Android Studio cannot compile the app

Comment: Did you update the sdk manager with the latest support libraries?

Comment: Yes, I had update to least version.

Comment: my app never used com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1

Comment: same issue as  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698451/how-to-resolve-android-gradle-issue-in-cordova-build